# specific json wont parse android studio using volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley, android-studio-2.3

Lately I have been trying to parse json in android studio using volley framework. When I use the code in the tutorial that I read, everything works just fine. However, when I try to parse my own json, something is not working.

This is my json code

```
JsonObjectRequest objectrequest = new JsonObjectRequest(hondenpoepURL, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject type = response.getJSONObject("type");

                JSONArray features = response.getJSONArray("features");




                for (int i = 0; i < features.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject bak = features.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONObject geometry = bak.getJSONObject("geometry");
                    JSONArray coordinates = geometry.getJSONArray("coordinates");

                    double latitude = coordinates.getDouble(1);
                    double longitude = coordinates.getDouble(0);


                    data +=  "latitude: " + latitude + "\nlongitude: " + longitude +
                            "\n\n";

                }


                results.setText(data);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                }
            }


    );

    requestQueue.add(objectrequest);
```

and this is my json url:
http://portaal-gem-lwd.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/1f505f23ef0a4f92aa32b0c8b98e8cbf_0.geojson

The problem is that it simply does not give an output.

Thanks in advance

PS. this is the url to the tutorial I read https://www.thorntech.com/2016/03/parsing-json-android-using-volley-library/

Comment: I tried following the link to your JSON, but I ended up downloading a file which i am really not comfortable opening on my computer. So, I could not check the validity of the JSON. Try using websites like [json lint](https://jsonlint.com) to check the validity of your JSON. Also look into your log data or exceptions / errors, if any. You should post those as well if they exist.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to log the response and to log the data.

I think Volley is using a Thread which is not the UI one that's why you can't just do a setText from here.

Answer (score 0):

On me it is working to set text to textview from inside of volley response function